# How to Copy an int4 ARRAY into int8 vector

Tags: c++, kernel, buffer, opencl

my ***array1*** is size 8, but in the kernel it is declared as ***int4***, how do i copy its  contents into vector ***int8 v***? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is my kernel .cl

```
__kernel void A2T1( __global int4 *a1, 
                    __global int *a2,
                    __global int *out ) {

    int8 v;

    int8 v1;
    int8 v2;
    int8 results;
    int8 mask;

    v = vload8(0, a1);

    v1 = vload8(0, a2);
    v2 = vload8(1, a2);

    mask.s01234567 = v.s01234567 > 15;
    results = select(v2, v1, mask);

    vstore8(v, 0, out);
    vstore8(v1, 1, out);
    vstore8(v2, 2, out);
    vstore8(results, 3, out);
    }
```

This is how i declare my arrays and buffers in my main/host.

```
// declare data and memory objects
int array1[8];
int array2[16];
int output[32];
cl::Buffer arraybuffer1, arraybuffer2, outputbuffer;

// create buffers
arraybuffer1 = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_int) * 8, &array1[0]);
arraybuffer2 = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_int) * 16, &array2[0]);
outputbuffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_int) * 32);

// set kernel arguments
kernel.setArg(0, arraybuffer1);
kernel.setArg(1, arraybuffer2); 
kernel.setArg(2, outputbuffer);

// enqueue kernel for execution
queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Casting the pointer
2. Vector literals

The third and simplest option would be to declare the kernel parameter as `__global int*` instead of `__global int4*` but I assume your real kernel is actually more complex and the vector annotation is helpful elsewhere in your code.

#### Casting

Casting an `int4*` to an `int*` should be safe - OpenCL is more relaxed about pointer casting than standard C; the main hazard is alignment. Alignment of `int4` is guaranteed to be stricter than `int`, so we're on the safe side.

So the code would look like this:

```
v = vload8(0, (global int*)a1);
```

#### Literals

Vector types in OpenCL have a special literal syntax. (See section 6.1.6, *Vector Literals* in the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf)) With this, you can combine 2 `int4` values into an `int8`:

```
v = (int8)(a1[0], a1[1]);
```